# How to avoid the flickering on taskbar in .net winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

i am using normal Form2.Show() and From1.Hide() to navigate the Form1 to Form2.
Application button is disappearing and appearing on the task bar while navigating just like flickering.

How to avoid this flickering?

Comment: can you show the sequence of command you use to show and hide forms? please post some code

Comment: Here is the code..
private void btnLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Background objBackground = new Background();
            objBackground.Show();
            this.Hide();
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You should have one main form which will be showing in taskbar. And all child forms should be set ShowInTaskBar = false. When ever, button on taskbar is clicked, application should activate / minimize the current visible child. This way you wont see button changing in taskbar. But personally I dont see any issue with current flickering, it is by default and there is nothing wrong with it.